# Simplified calculation to find Lagrange point $L_1$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, stability

I'm trying to find the position of Lagrange point L1 in the earth-moon system. To make the whole thing easier (I thought) I don't care about the sun's influence or any other forces than the gravitational force of earth and moon. So it should work out like this:
$$G\frac{mM_{E}}{D-d_M}=G\frac{mM_M}{d_M}$$

Where $D$ is the distance between earth and moon and $d_M$ the distance of L1 from the moon.
So I have to find out $d_M$ and got to this formula:
$$d_M=D+D\frac{M_M}{M_E}$$
Which, obviously, is rubbish for L1 (as $d_M$ is further away than the moon using this formula). I'm feeling quite stupid right now, this can not be that hard...

Comment: Two things: you can see in your very first equation that the point $L_1$ is independent of the mass, $m$, of your test object as it cancels out from both sides. Second, it appears that you forgot that the force of gravity is an inverse square force, so your distances in the denominator of each term should be _squared_.

Comment: You have the math and physics completely wrong. You need to look at things from the perspective of a rotating frame in which the Moon and Earth are not moving. Why? The answer is simple: That's how the Lagrange points are defined. Whether that definition is meaningful is another question (aside: it is meaningful). When you finish, you'll get a fifth order polynomial. Here's the sad part: Fifth order polynomials in general don't have a nice closed form solution. This is one of them.

Comment: I think Wikipedia has a detailed discussion of this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point).